# Python Code Issue_Raspberry Pi 3 Model B + 4 Water Flow Sensors + IDLE Shell

Tags: python-3.x, export-to-csv, raspberry-pi3, sd-card

I have a problem running this code on raspberry pi 3 model B. This code runs on python file and should output on idle shell. The objective of this project is to log sensor data of YF-S201 Water Flow Sensors, where 2 water flow-in and 2 water flow-out data will be recorded in sd card and logged into csv file automatically. But somehow the IDLE shell shows only "=== RESTART: /home/irfanfyp/Documents/datalogger2_waterflow/waterflow_csv.py ===" output and the csv file generated was 0 bytes.

Here is the code:
`
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import csv

```
# Set up GPIO pins for water flow sensors
flow_in_pin_1 = 14
flow_in_pin_2 = 15
flow_out_pin_1 = 18
flow_out_pin_2 = 23

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(flow_in_pin_1, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(flow_in_pin_2, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(flow_out_pin_1, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(flow_out_pin_2, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

# Define flow rate conversion factor (from pulses to liters per minute)
flow_rate_factor = 2.25

# Set up CSV file for data logging
csv_file_path = 'datalogger2_waterflow.csv'  # Replace with the actual path of your CSV file
csv_file = open(csv_file_path, mode='w')
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
csv_writer.writerow(['timestamp', 'flow_in_1', 'flow_in_2', 'flow_out_1', 'flow_out_2'])

# Define function for reading water flow sensor data
def read_flow_data(pin):
    pulse_count = 0
    last_pulse_time = time.time()
    while True:
        try:
            GPIO.wait_for_edge(pin, GPIO.FALLING)
            pulse_count += 1
            flow_rate = pulse_count / (time.time() - last_pulse_time) * flow_rate_factor
            last_pulse_time = time.time()
            return flow_rate
        except Exception as e:
            if isinstance(e, KeyboardInterrupt):
                raise e
            else:
                print("Error:", e)
                return None

# Main loop for reading and logging water flow sensor data
try:
    while True:
        timestamp = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        flow_in_1 = read_flow_data(flow_in_pin_1)
        flow_in_2 = read_flow_data(flow_in_pin_2)
        flow_out_1 = read_flow_data(flow_out_pin_1)
        flow_out_2 = read_flow_data(flow_out_pin_2)
        csv_writer.writerow([timestamp, flow_in_1, flow_in_2, flow_out_1, flow_out_2])
        csv_file.flush()
        print("Timestamp:", timestamp)
        print("Flow In 1:", flow_in_1)
        print("Flow In 2:", flow_in_2)
        print("Flow Out 1:", flow_out_1)
        print("Flow Out 2:", flow_out_2)
        time.sleep(60)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
    csv_file.close()`
```

I expect that the data will output on IDLE Shell and csv file will have stored some data from sensor reading. I have rewired and tested the continuity of connected sensors but still nothing. please help.

Comment: If you run the code in python directly, the output should appear is a system terminal.  I know nothing of RPi, but this does not appear to be an IDLE issue.  Perhaps `GPIO.wait_for_edge(pin, GPIO.FALLING)` never return.  Put `print('before')` and `print('after')` before and after than call.  If you see 'after' printed, move the print statements until you find where execution is stuck.